# Netbeans IDE 8.1 Cannot lock read-only file

Tags: netbeans, jsp

Hola me acaban de pasar a trabajar con el proyecto de alguien más en netbeans con jsp. Pero cuando trato de editar el código, me aparece hasta abajo una pequeño reseña que me dice que el documento solo se puede leer.

> Cannot lock read-only file

Quisiera saber si alguien tiene idea de como desbloquearlo. Todo el proyecto,todos sus archivos me dicen los mismo, y por tanto no puedo avanzar. Agradecería su ayuda. De antemano muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente asegura que donde se encuentre el proyecto tu tengas permisos para poder cambiar la propiedad `Read-only` de los archivos, de otra forma tienes que revisar con el administrador.

En cambio si tienes permisos para realizar este cambio, puedes realizarlo manualmente eliminando la propiedad `Read-only` del archivo(s)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra opción es utilizar un plugin para realizarlo desde la IDE, puedes buscar en el [sitio oficial Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/search_result.html?cx=006102455337629464213%3Amt38ytkbuak&cof=FORID%3A11&q=Read-Only%2FWrite%20status&x=0&y=0&siteurl=plugins.netbeans.org%2Fplugin%2F23133%2Fswitch-file-read-write-access&ref=www.google.com.mx%2F&ss=39j1521j2) por ejemplo:

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/23133/switch-file-read-write-access

o

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/6454/change-state-of-read-write-access

Por ejemplo para el primer plugin que es el que suelo usar, descargargalo y ve a:

`Tools` > `Plugins` > `Downloaded` , seleccionalo e instalalo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al instalar el plugin puedes cambiar la propiedad del archivo, dando click al candado mostrado en la esquina inferior derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias man me salvaste el día.

Comment: @EduardoRawrdríguez excelente, que bien pudiste solucionar tu problema, saludos!